# FTP Service in OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, ftp, server, osx-yosemite

-- FTP SERVICE IN OS X YOSEMITE --

I've started the FTP service with the following command in Yosemite:

```
 sudo -s launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist
```

Then,I need to configure it. Does someone know which file it is configured by? Also how do I set '`chroot`' it to a directory.

Answer (score 4):

The `OS X` ftp daemon is configured by the following files:

```
/etc/ftpd.conf
/etc/ftpchroot
/etc/ftpusers
```

example file: `cat /usr/share/ftpd/examples/ftpd.conf`

**/private/etc/ftpusers**

> The ftpusers file provides user access control for tnftpd(8) by
>   defining which users may login.
>
> If the ftpusers file does not exist, all users are denied access.

example file: `cat /usr/share/ftpd/examples/ftpusers`

**/private/etc/ftpchroot**

> The file /private/etc/ftpchroot is used to determine which users will
>   have their session's root directory changed (using
>   chroot(2)), either to the directory specified in the ftpd.conf(5)
>   chroot directive  (if set), or to the home directory of the user.  If
>   the file does not exist, the root directory change  is not performed.
>
> The syntax is similar to ftpusers, except that the class argument is
>   ignored.  If there's a positive  match, the session's root directory
>   is changed.  No further comparisons are attempted after the first 
>   successful match.  This syntax is backward-compatible with the old
>   syntax.

example file: `cat /usr/share/ftpd/examples/ftpchroot`

To `chroot` a directory, (eg. `guest`):

```
chroot guest /path/to/guest/accessable/ftp
```

---

More Infomation: [ftpd.conf](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/ftpd.conf.5.html), [ftpusers/ftpchroot](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/ftpchroot.5.html), [chroot](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/chroot.2.html)